# URL rewrite to redirect all URL variants to https://www.example.com

Tags: regex, https, url-rewriting, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008

I have a URL and I have applied an SSL certificate to the www variant https://www.example.com. I would like all variations of this domain to point to https://www.example.com,

So for example the following domains should redirect to https://www.example.com:

- http://www.example.com
- http://example.com
- https://example.com

The website is hosted on a windows 2008 server running IIS7.5 and I have created some rules in the web.config file using URL Rewrite. However the following domains do not redirect:

- http://example.com
- https://example.com

Here are the rules I currently have:

```
    <!-- Redirect http non www to https www -->
    <rule name="Redirect http://example.com to www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example.com" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>

    <!-- Redirect http to https -->
    <rule name="Redirect http to https" enabled="true">
        <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

I would appreciate some assistance in getting this to work using a URL rewrite. Ideally I would prefer to replace the above with a single rule.

Answer (score 4):

Let's follow the logic below, this is using "Regex".

Match any URL being passed in, then match any of the follow conditions.

1. If the host starts matches `example.com` then redirect
2. If the port `80` is being used than redirect.

This will cover redirecting http to https and anything example.com to www.example.com

```
<rule name="Do It All" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" />
    <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="^80$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks Henry for this. It has definitely improved. I tested it in Firefox after I cleared the cache of cookies and history. Previously when I typed example.com it immediately redirected to https://example.com which flagged the security warning. Now it redirects to https://www.example.com which is what I want.

The problem remains however that if I type in https://example.com it does not redirect at all and the security warning appears.

Comment: If it helps, the SSL certificate is only applied to www.example.com and not example.com. I wanted to avoid the extra cost hoping that the redirect would do the trick.

Comment: Are you applying this at the Global Level or the in Web.config? Try moving it to the global level before it even reaches your website.  Click on the server name in IIS and apply it there, it will go into your applicationhost.config.

Comment: The certificate is added at the server level within the "Server Certificates" application. At the site level I created a binding for https then selected the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using two rules, the first to redirect all non-https to https without `stopProcessing=true`, and the second to redirect all non-www to www, like so.

```
<rule name="HTTPS Redirect">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
<rule name="Redirect to www">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Also, you don't need `appendQueryString=true`; `{R:1}` appends the query string. `stopProcessing=true` is also not necessary, especially if you don't have any other rules following. Most of the time though, if you *do* have rules following, you want them to execute after the URL has been redirected to https and reformatted to www.